# pbs: input file not correclty updated

Tags: pbs

I am using a PBS queuing system and submit a job with the following bash jobscript

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=1:30:00
./aprogram $input
```

using qsub -v "input=myinputfile" script.job

This works fine except for the fact that if I run the job, change something in the input file without renaming it and rerun the job shortly thereafter, the input file the program aprogram gets is still the old input file.

Obviously the file is hiding somewhere and is not reread if the time is to short (waiting a few minutes does the trick). Does anybody have an idea where I could wipe the file out such that it is correctly read?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all PBS queuing systems, but Torque only makes a local copy of the script; it doesn't parse the script to figure out what the script uses and make local copies of those things. In other words, if you are using Torque it is not doing this. I'm not sure what it could be, although I would try to track down what is refreshed every few minutes to see if that could be it.